# Regex for removing Commas within brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I am stuck at writing the regex which needs me to remove comma inside brackets. The commas outside should stay as is

Here's what I need

Input :(37.400809377128354, -122.05618455969392) , (37.3931723332768, -121.89276292883454)

Output :(37.400809377128354 -122.05618455969392) , (37.3931723332768 -121.89276292883454)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex which uses positive look ahead to discard matching a comma that is outside the parenthesis,

```
,(?=[^()]*\))
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FNRo9g/1)**

```js
var s = "(37.400809377128354, -122.05618455969392),(37.3931723332768, -121.89276292883454)";
console.log(s.replace(/,(?=[^()]*\))/g, ''));
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

ES '18 Solution using Look-behind Assertions

```js
const s = "(37.400809377128354, -122.05618455969392),(37.3931723332768, -121.89276292883454)";

console.log(
    s.replace(/(?<=\d),/g, '')
);
```

[ECMAScript® 2018 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-Assertion)